# Waiting for a callback

Tags: node.js, callback

I'm working with callbacks to improve my program's efficiency. I would like to wait for my 'a' variable to get the value from callback if it hasn't already at some point. My code looks like this:

```
function myFunction(callback){
    request("url", function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) 
        {
            result = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body));
            return callback(null, result);
        } 
        else 
        {
            return callback(error, null);
        }
    });
}

var a = myFunction(function(err, data){
    if(!err)
    {
        return(data);
    }
    else
    {
        return(err);
    }
});

//A CHUNK OF CODE EXECUTES HERE 

//I'D LIKE TO CHECK IF THE a VARIABLE GOT THE VALUE (if the callback was executed), note that I don't want to nest the chunk inside the callback, but rather I'd like to check that outside function callback via IF statement/loop or some similar alternative

//MORE CODE CONNECTED TO THE CALLBACK
```

Any ideas on how I can wait for the variable to get the value if it didn't get it already by the time that the chunk of code is executed? I know that the sole intention of using callbacks is to not wait but in this instance it is necessary for me so just don't bother being annoying please :)

Comment: You should use promises.

Comment: `return callback(null, result)` doesn't do what you think it does in that context. That return statement only applies to the anonymous function, `myFunction` has no `return` statements so it always returns `undefined`.

Comment: You should try async/await

Comment: @Paulpro Yes I noticed that, but that's no problem as I can just store the data into another variable before return. My goal is just to make sure that I know when that callback was executed

Comment: @quo91 The whole point of the callback is to run code after the request has completed. You can put all your code that needs to run after the request inside the callback, including calling other functions. All the code you put outside (where you have "A CHUNK OF CODE EXECUTES HERE") is guaranteed to run before the callback.

Comment: @Paulpro I know that and that works as intended, but if I put everything inside a callback that would end up nasty with the amout of requests I have. I'm just looking for a simple way to check if the callback has executed outside the function itself, because after the check that info will be processed. The info will parse inside the callback tho.

Comment: @Paulpro I guess I could do that with a for loop simply checking for a variable value and that value would change inside the callback (loop would run untill the default set value would change), but that would be unefficient and nasty.

Comment: @quo91 That wouldn't work because JavaScript is single-threaded. The callback won't run while the loop is running, so it would become an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've ended up making a little compromise (had to nest), but the code works as intended:

```
var something;

function myFunction(callback){
    request("url", function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) 
        {
            result = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body));
            return callback(null, result);
        } 
        else 
        {
            return callback(error, null);
        }
    });
}

var a = myFunction(function(err, data){
    if(!err)
    {
        something = data;
        return(data);
    }
    else
    {
        return(err);
    }
});

//A CHUNK OF CODE EXECUTES HERE 

var something_cachedValue=something;
doStuff();
function doStuff() {
    if(something===something_cachedValue) {
        setTimeout(doStuff, 10);
        return;
    }

    something_cachedValue = something;
    //MORE CODE CONNECTED TO THE CALLBACK
}
```

So basically I'm checking if the callback has completed every 10ms by re-calling the function. When it's completed, the "//MORE CODE CONNECTED TO THE CALLBACK" executes. Not the cleanest and most fancy way to do it but it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest trying async/await and the [request-promise-native](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native) module, this keeps the syntax very simple. If the call fails for some reason an error will be thrown, this is easy to catch:

For example:

```
const rp = require('request-promise-native');

async function testAsyncRequest() {
    try {
        let promise = rp('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts');
        // Do some stuff here...
        let result = await promise;
        console.log("Result: ", result);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Something went wrong: ${err.message}`);
    }
}

testAsyncRequest();
```

Comment: Yeah that does work, but not the way I'd like it to. My intention is to initiate the function and then the chunk of code executes (without waiting). After that chunk is done I'd check/wait if that request is done and process that information. I'd like that to improve the time it takes to execute my code.

Comment: Ah yes, I see, well remember that the async function will not block, so it will execute quickly. The result will be populated as soon as it is available. It's really just a callback but with simpler syntax.

Comment: @quo91 I think you can use a variant of this to do what you want. It would look something like `let requestPromise = rp( "url" ); // DO STUFF BEFORE WAITING HERE; let result = await requestPromise; // DO STUFF WITH THE RESPONSE HERE`

Comment: I've updated as per @Paulpros comment, you can run whatever you like while waiting for the promise to resolve.  You could also run some code after the async function exits. It will likely complete before the request is returned.